# Allow empty/no selection in DevExpress' LookUpEdit

Tags: c#, combobox, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a form containing a DevExpress `LookUpEdit` (Windows Forms) which is bound to a list of objects with several displayed properties. The `EditValue` property is set to another object's property which will receive the selected value.

The user may select any item from the list of objects, but I also want to allow empty selections i.e. the `EditValue` would become `null` and the displayed text should be the default `[No entry]` then.

How could this be accomplished the easiest way?

Currently there's no way to clear the value after it has been set once.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:
1. User can press Ctrl+Del to clear the value
2. However, this is not intuitive. What I do is add another value to the bound list.

```
var list = GetOriginalList(); // <- get all possible values
list.Add(new MyItem("[empty]", null)); // <- display name and ID
```

Comment: I have already read about this Ctrl+Del, but it seems not to work. Probably an "empty" value is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

In form load :

```
 LookUpEditName.Properties.AllowNullInput = true ;
 LookUpEditName.Properties.NullText = "No entry";
```

and use `LookUpEditName.EditValue = null;` to clear the value

Comment: `LookUpEditName.Properties.AllowNullInput=true;` enables that the user may press CTRL+DEL do clear the box, but that is not very user-friendly. There must be something clickable to clear the box as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add Cancel Button to your Lookup Edit and add reset code in Button Click event

Dim editor As LookUpEdit = CType(sender, LookUpEdit)

```
    If editor.Properties.Buttons.IndexOf(e.Button) = 0 Then
        YourLookUpEdit.EditValue = DBNull.Value
    End If
```